# find - globbing in path to search

Tags: find

My question is simple and I couldn't find answer on google:
why if I type:

```
find *h
```

or

```
find *g
```

or any other character following the star, the result is all files in current and subdirectories ?
the same result is also for

```
find *
```

which is obvious. I guess the star(*) acts here as the directory where to start searching, not the file pattern to search for. So the * extends as 'all directories in current directory'. So in this case it will search in all directories and find all files, which is the expected behavior. But why if I provide as directory to start searching '*g' it finds also all files ? even though there is no single directory which starts with 'g' ?

Comment: This should be posted on unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The wildcard is expanded by the shell. So it becomes the list of starting points.

Comment: Type `echo *h` or `echo *g`. You'll see that the shell expands the wildcard. Those filenames become the list of starting points to `find`.

Comment: When I typed echo *g the result was an empty list, as I expected. I dont understand the behavior of 'find *g', why it list all files, including those in subdirectories. Sorry Barmar, next time I will ask on unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you give an empty list to `find`, it defaults to searching the current directory.

Comment: Normally, if a wildcard doesn't match anything, it expands to itself. It sounds like you have the `nullglob` shell option set, so it expands to an empty list.

Comment: Thats correct Barman, I found out exactly the same thing right now, thanks ! And sorry for question but I had to know that.

Comment: And thats true, I have the null_glob option set.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is not how it works. `*g` is expanded by the shell to all the files and directories in the current directory which end with `g` and then `find` acts on that list.

As @Barmar points out in a comment, what you describe sounds like you have no matches on `*g` and the `nullglob` option set in your shell, which will cause a wildcard expression with no matches to expand into the empty string. (The default behavior is to leave it unexpanded, which would cause an error message from `find`.)

Comment: yes, but the thing is that there is no directory ending with 'g' and even though the command list all files in all subdirectories, result from my console: `./log_05.txt
./Asad.cpp
./dir3
./dir3/asd3.cpp
./dir3/asd2.cpp
./dir3/asd1.cpp
./dir3/dir_nested
./asd.cpp
./log_02.txt
./log_06.txt
./log_01.txt
`